# Wrong Z values using gdal2xyz in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, convert

I have a DEM `.tif` data. I am trying to convert it with gdal2xyz to ASCII data.

The result is always wrong. `X` and `Y` values are correct but `Z` value is wrong.

On the next image below, you can see the parameters. I changed even the band but it did not help. Any suggestions?

I am working with [EPSG: 31468 | DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4](https://epsg.io/31468).

[image]

[image]

You can find the result (CSV-data) in the next image:

[image]

Comment: Which projection is that?

Comment: the projection I took from Meta data :+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: can you add `gdalinfo` results on the file

Comment: Have you tried transforming the DEM to EPSG:25832 (UTM32N)?

Comment: I transformed the DEM to UTM32N projection but it did not help.

Comment: @ Ian Turton: I add the protocoll of gdal2xyz

Comment: Are all the values in the .csv file those very small numbers (seem like minus infinity)? They may stand for nodata.

Comment: @ user30184  I see that there are height values in .tif-data. I changed also the band to 2 or 3 but no results.